# I can't clear the graph output whenever I click a button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

this is more of a follow-up to my last question, but I'm trying to build a gui using ipywigets. The problem I still have is still related to my last post - clearing the output. I have changed the code slightly and now, when I click a button, it shows me the graph along with the nba player info. The info now works, but the graph won't clear. And I don't know how to solve this. Any advice?

[*this is the link to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674515/the-clear-output-isnt-clearing-the-output-whenever-i-click-a-new-button)

```
#sample graph

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x/4

a = np.array(['sales', 'customer', 'interaction'])
b = np.array([300, 200, 1000])
```

```
#button function

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import IPython
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
output = ipywidgets.widgets.Output()

def on_btn_click(btn):
  with output:
    clear_output()
    plt.close()
    if btn.description == 'Avery Bradley':
      print (file.loc[0]), plt.plot(x,y)

    if btn.description == 'Jae Crowder':
      print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b)


    '''if btn.description == 'John Holland':
      print (file.loc[2])
    if btn.description == 'R.J. Hunter':
      print (file.loc[3])
    if btn.description == 'Jonas Jerebko':
      print (file.loc[4])
    if btn.description == 'Amir Johnson':
      print (file.loc[5])
    if btn.description == 'Jordan Mickey':
      print (file.loc[6])
    if btn.description == 'Kelly Olynyk':
      print (file.loc[7])
    if btn.description == 'Terry Rozier':
      print (file.loc[8])
    if btn.description == 'Marcus Smart':
      print (file.loc[9])
    if btn.description == 'Jared Sullinger':
      print (file.loc[10])
    if btn.description == 'Isaiah Thomas':
      print (file.loc[11])'''
```

```
#create button

button_list = []
for i in range (0,12):
  button = ipywidgets.widgets.Button(description=image_name[i]['name'])
  button.on_click(on_btn_click)
  button_list.append(button)
```

```
#resize button

 grid = widgets.Grid(1,6, header_column=True, header_row=True)
 newsize = (100,100)

 for (row, col) in grid:
  index = row*6+col
  print("\n")
  display(image_name[index]['image'].resize(newsize))
  display(button_list[index])

 for (row, col) in grid:
  index = row*6+col
  print("\n")
  display(image_name[index+6]['image'].resize(newsize))
  display(button_list[index+6])

display(output)
```

I know the problem lies somewhere in the button function code and I've tried the following (but none of them worked):

```
#button function

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import IPython
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
output = ipywidgets.widgets.Output()

def on_btn_click(btn):
  with output:
    clear_output()
    plt.close()                               <------- this line
    if btn.description == 'Avery Bradley':
      print (file.loc[0]), plt.plot(x,y)

    if btn.description == 'Jae Crowder':
      print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b)
```

```
#button function

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import IPython
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
output = ipywidgets.widgets.Output()

def on_btn_click(btn):
  with output:
    clear_output()
    if btn.description == 'Avery Bradley':
      print (file.loc[0]), plt.plot(x,y)
      clear_output(), print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b) 
      print (file.loc[1]), clear_output(), plt.bar(a,b)
      print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b), clear_output()

    if btn.description == 'Jae Crowder':
      clear_output(), print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b)  <------- 
      print (file.loc[1]), clear_output(), plt.bar(a,b)  <-------   tried all 3 of these line
      print (file.loc[1]), plt.bar(a,b), clear_output()  <-- (and even switched clear_output() for plt.close())
```